# Shifting a char array by N spots

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am trying to shift a character array by a number of specified spots.

For example, if **n = 2**, I would like my array "Hello." to become "llo."
I've tried the following:

```
memmove(array, array+2, sizeof array - sizeof *array);
```

But it does not work. If:

```
char *array = "Hello."
```

I would like array to be "llo."

Any help would be appreciated. I've no clue how to do something this simple.

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, with different solutions. In order to get the best answers for you, you should remove one of the tags.

Comment: For `array` as you specify, `sizeof array` is exactly `sizeof (char *)` and has no relationship whatsoever to the string literal `"Hello."`      Also, modifying a string literal (which your code does, indirectly) is undefined behaviour.      You need to do homework to understand (1) what is the difference between a pointer and an array (you are falling into a beginner trap of assuming they are the same thing)   (2)  understand how a string literal like `"Hello."` is actually represented in memory, and that it should not be modified.

Comment: Do you really want to move the array content, or would it be enough to move the pointer two steps to the right? Like this: `array += 2;`

Answer (score 1):

In the case of

```
char *array = "Hello.";
```

Then the variable `array` isn't actually an array. It's a pointer to the first element of a **constant** array containing the literal string.

As literal strings are constant, they can not be modified, and any attempt to do it anyway leads to *undefined behavior*. And in fact your compiler should have warned you about it (listen to your compiler, and treat all messages (even warnings) as errors that must be fixed).

The correct definition would be

```
const char *pointer = "Hello.";
```

To solve your problem use an *actual* array:

```
char array[] = "Hello.";
```

Or better yet use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and its facilities. Like the ability to easily create [sub-strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

There's also the problem with `sizeof` when using pointers. The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to. To reliable get the length of a C-style null-terminated string one must use `strlen`. And the size of an array is the size of the whole array, including possible null-terminator and other possibly uninitialized elements, while `strlen` only gets the number of characters in the string up to (but not including) the null-terminator.

Also note that the size of a single `char` is defined to always be `1`, no matter its actual bit-with. Which means `sizeof *array` will always be `1`, so you might as well save some effort and write the number instead.

---

The above answer is from a C++ perspective. The semantics of literal strings and pointers to them is *very* different in C!

In C literal strings aren't actually constant. However it's not allowed to modify them, making them in essence read-only. Attempting to modify a string literal in C still leads to undefined behavior, but the reason is a different one.